# Add Data in Access using VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I was trying to make a program in VB that accepts user information then saves it in MS access. I already connected MS access and Visual Basic ... The Code Works but it does not add the values inputted by the user in the MS access Table..

```
Public Sub AddNewStudent()
    Dim firstname, middlename As String
    con.Open()
    Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\user.mdf;Integrated Security=True;user Instance=True"

    Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()

    mycommand.Connection = myconnect
    mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, Cellphone Number, Course)" & _
                            "VALUES(" & Me.firstnameTB.Text & ",'" & Me.midnameTB.Text & "')"
    firstname = firstnameTB.Text
    middlename = midnameTB.Text

    Try
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.firstnameTB.Text()
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@middlename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.midnameTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@lastnameTB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.lastnameTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@addressTB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.addressTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@cpnumTB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.cpnumTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@courseCB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.courseCB.Text
        MsgBox("Successfully added new student")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
    myconnect.Close()
```

Comment: Nothing won't save without calling `ExecuteNonQuery`... Just a thought as @jmcilhinney already cleared other things up...

Comment: @Codexer, I didn't even notice that, there were so many other issues. Interesting that the OP said "The Code Works but...". I'm not sure what their definition of working is but it's different to mine. I'm guessing they meant that it compiles.

Comment: Yes it would compile, but the error he would never see because the command wasn't being executed.

Comment: One additional thought, looking at the connection string it appears this may had been done using the ide data wizard where in this case if the database was copied into the project the default action when compiling is to copy the database to the bin\debug folder (as indicated when adding the database to the project) and if this is the case review the following which guides you through changing this setting "if needed". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you specify that six columns are to be inserted into but you then only provide two values.  Secondly, you add parameters to your command but there are no parameters in your SQL code.  You need to provide the same number of values as columns and those values need to be parameters.  There are also a couple of other issues, like a column name with a space in it and calling AddWithValue improperly.

```
Public Sub AddNewStudent()
    Dim firstname, middlename As String
    con.Open()
    Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\user.mdf;Integrated Security=True;user Instance=True"

    Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()

    mycommand.Connection = myconnect
    mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, [Cellphone Number], Course)" & _
                            "VALUES(@firstname, middlename, @lastnameTB, @addressTB, @cpnumTB, @courseCB)"
    firstname = firstnameTB.Text
    middlename = midnameTB.Text

    Try
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.firstnameTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@middlename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.midnameTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@lastnameTB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.lastnameTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@addressTB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.addressTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@cpnumTB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.cpnumTB.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@courseCB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Me.courseCB.Text
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox("Successfully added new student")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
    myconnect.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

change the command text like this

```
 mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, [Cellphone Number], Course)" & _
                            "VALUES(@firstname, @middlename, @lastnameTB, @addressTB, @cpnumTB, @courseCB)"
```

change all of your lines setting data like this (its more convenient )

```
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseCB", courseCB.Text)
```

and finally write this code before
 **MsgBox("Successfully added new student")**

```
mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery
```